# download file FROM web TO flask server

Tags: python, file, flask, download

My flask app should download files from urls which are posted to my app by a json object. 
The files should be downloaded for further processing. I do not get an error message. A lot of tutorials are about how a user uploads a file, but this is not my case. Can anyone help?

```
import os


from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import urllib.request as web

app = Flask(__name__)
download_folder=os.path.join(app.instance_path,'downloads')
app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'] = download_folder


@app.route('/syncaudio', methods=['POST'])
def syncaudio():
    files = request.get_json(force=True)

    for file_url in files['syncFileUrls']:
        local_file = os.path.join(app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], file_url.rsplit('/')[-1])
        web.urlretrieve(file_url, local_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`urlretrieve(file_url,local_file)` is the right way of doing it, there is nothing specific to Flask.

I suggest you to try in a Python interpreter to see if that works:

```py
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://some/url', '/some/file/location.txt')
```

If that works, this means your code is never getting executed.

You may want to print the value of `files` to see if the list is not empty.

Comment: Thanks! `files` is not the problem. I did not create the `download` folder properly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

for downloading FROM web TO flask server I do not need to create a folder like this:

`download_folder=os.path.join(app.instance_path,'downloads')
app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'] = download_folder`

I just have to create a download folder via:

`os.makedirs('downloads')`

really simpel :)